# Apache Tika and RTF with Tables (cell, border, etc)

Tags: java, html, rtf, apache-tika

G'day!

I try use *Apache Tika 2.5.0* for convert *RTF-based* content to *HTML *and stuck with convert tables from rtf-content (it was tags as *\cellx \clbrdr \brdr* and so on). Tika convert this tags as a paragraph 



.

I try use many SAX handlers (transformers, ToHTMLContentHandler and so on), but it make no positive effects.
I think, it's possibly to configure RTFParser by metadata, handler or context, but I fount no example.

My convert method code:

```
public static void converterRTF2HTML2(File rtfFile, File htmlFile, Charset cpOut) throws TransformerConfigurationException, TikaException, IOException, SAXException {
    InputStream rtfStream = new FileInputStream(rtfFile);

    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String rtfDetect = tika.detect(rtfFile); // detect as 'application/rtf'
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, rtfDetect);

    OutputStream htmlStream = new FileOutputStream(htmlFile);

    SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)
            SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
    TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();

    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, cpOut.name());
    handler.setResult(new StreamResult(htmlStream));

    ContentHandler handlerToXML = new ToXMLContentHandler();

      // handlers that I try
/////////////////
    ExpandedTitleContentHandler handler1 = new ExpandedTitleContentHandler(handler);
    //TaggedContentHandler handler1 = new TaggedContentHandler(handler);
    //TextAndAttributeContentHandler handler2 = new TextAndAttributeContentHandler(handler);

    ToHTMLContentHandler toHTMLContentHandler = new ToHTMLContentHandler(htmlStream, "UTF-8");
    //XHTMLContentHandler toXHTMLContentHandler = new XHTMLContentHandler(toHTMLContentHandler, metadata);

    //RichTextContentHandler handler1 = new RichTextContentHandler(rtfStream);
///////////////////

    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();


    //RTFParser parser = new RTFParser();
    Parser parser = tika.getParser();
    parser.parse(rtfStream, handler1, metadata, context);


    htmlStream.flush();
    rtfStream.close();
    htmlStream.close();

}
```

try different handlers and parsers

Comment: I'm not seeing any support in https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-parsers/tika-parsers-standard/tika-parsers-standard-modules/tika-parser-microsoft-module/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/rtf/TextExtractor.java for those RTF tags, so I think you're going to have to contribute your first patch to Apache Tika to add the missing support....

Comment: Looks like that =(